# Unity3D - How to get the angle between 2 points as a vector

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine, angle, unityscript

I have run into problems while trying to get my unity code done (using Javascript/Unityscript), so the question is:
How can i get the angle between two points (as Vector3s) and the angle as another Vector3

my code is :

```
var Offset : Vector3 = (0,0,3);
var angle1 : Vector3;
angle1 = Vector3.Angle(Vector3(0,0,0), Offset);
```

The error that i got is : 
BCE0022: Cannot convert 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'.

I looked around, but was only able to find what i already knew.

Thanks for any help in advance !

-Etaash

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by getting the angle as a vector. How do you want to represent an angle as a vector? If you could give an example of the input you want and the output you want with specific numbers that might help.

Comment: @CiscoIPPhone The input that will be given is two points (as Vector3, ie: (0,0,0)  and (0,0,3)). The output i want to see is the angle between them. I should be able to seperately pick out the Z angle, Y angle etc.If you use Unity an example of this angle can be seen in the transform component menu.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the syntax error letiagoalves mentioned, [Vector3.Angle](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html) returns a float, not a Vector3. You don't need to pre-define the angle variable, you can do it one line. Your final code should look like this:

```
var Offset : Vector3 = Vector3(0,0,3);
var angle1 = Vector3.Angle(Vector3(0,0,0), Offset);
```

Comment: How can i get it to return a Vector3 ?

Comment: You can't, that's not what an Angle is. Are you trying to get a vector that is a direction from one point to another?